# Default options for getPastEvents in web3js

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, dapps, events

I am trying to get the specific past events for my contract, named 'Transfer'; when I try to simply use the following code, it gives empty result.

```
myContract.getPastEvents("Transfer").then(function (event) {
    console.log(event);
})
//output is: []
```

While when I run with some optional arguments, it gives proper output as expected of two events from my contract.

```
myContract.getPastEvents("Transfer", { fromBlock: 25635490, toBlock: 25635656 }).then(function (event) {
    console.log(event);
})
//output is: Array[2] -- which is array of two events as expected
```

The contract is hosted on polygon mumbai testnet - https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x1d7f71e9dd4283B5b4431e7a51498f4C14b18715

And the reference to web3js documentation which cites that fromBlock and toBlock are optional arguments, so as a newbie I assume that it scans from block 0 to the latest block, please help me with this.

Contract.getPastEvents [Docs link](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#getpastevents)

> fromBlock/toBlock - Number|String|BN|BigNumber (optional): The block number (greater than or equal to) from which to get events on. Pre-defined block numbers as "earliest", "latest" and "pending" can also be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The default block is used for certain methods. You can override it by
> passing in the defaultBlock as last parameter. The default value is
> "latest".

`fromBlock` is set as "latest" by default, that's why you have no events.

> The default block parameters can be one of the following:

> Number|BN|BigNumber: A block number

> "earliest" - String: The genesis block

> "latest" - String: The latest block (current head of the blockchain) >

> "pending" - String: The currently mined block (including pending transactions)

but if you try "genesis" you may have an error similar to this:
`Error: Returned error: Blockheight too far in the past: eth_getLogs. Range of blocks allowed for your plan: 1000`, this means that your node does not allow you to search for events older than 1000 blocks.

In this case you can try to paid solutions (moralis, infura, etc.)

Comment: Ok so that makes sense, so by default the function will search from the "latest" block and to the "latest" block, meaning a total of 1 block only.?